# Design pattern for similar queries

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class with several methods with the similar purposes: to get the contact information from another API.

The interface looks like this:

```
interface ContactDao {
   Contact getContactById(int contactId);
   Contact getContactByContactGroup(int contactGroupId);
}
```

Is there a design pattern or solution to reduce the number of methods to get Contacts?

I've referred to https://thinkinginobjects.com/2012/08/26/dont-use-dao-use-repository/ so far.

Comment: ```getContactBy(int type, int val)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "select criteria" object.

```
public class ContactCriteria {

    private Integer type;
    private Integer val;

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public Integer getVal() {
        return val;
    }

}

interface ContactDao {
   Optional<Contact> getContact(ContactCriteria criteria);
   List<Contact> getContacts(ContactCriteria criteria);
}
```

When building a query, you check if given criteria exists and if true, build corresponding query predicate (using some query build facility). The predicates are joined with AND. Below example is based on QueryDSL:

```
import com.querydsl.core.BooleanBuilder;
import com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate;

public class ContactPredicate {
    private static QContact contact = QContact.contact;
    private ContactPredicate() {}

    public static Predicate forCriteria(ContactCriteria criteria) {
        BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();

        if (criteria.getType() != null) {
            predicate.and(contact.type.eq(criteria.getType()));
        }
        if (criteria.getVal() != null) {
            predicate.and(contact.val.eq(criteria.getVal()));
       }
       return predicate;
    }

}
```

This is simple example. You can build more complex  criteria->predicated (e.g. date range, etc.)

Comment: Pretty much what I ended up using. Added a enum to represent the different types of inputs that can be used.